# How do I draw shapes inside a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I know how to draw different shapes using tikz, like this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and 1.5)
      (0,2.5) circle (1)
      (2.5,0) circle (1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would like to put a number of different shapes together inside a node, and I couldn't yet find a simple way to do that. I will make a little figure to include in a large diagram which is already made of several nodes.

If this is not possible, or not easy, then how do I include a JPG or EPS file in a node?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`TiKZ 3.0` introduced `pics`. They are not exactly `nodes` but they allow to draw complex figures and manage them as a single one.

Search for them in TeX.SX and you'll find some more examples. Two of them:

- [Rotating pictures and labels together with pics in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173456/rotating-pictures-and-labels-together-with-pics-in-tikz/173459#173459) (this one also shows how to include a .pdf graphics into a `node`)
- [How to create something like a function (procedure, macros, etc.) in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172484/how-to-create-something-like-a-function-procedure-macros-etc-in-tikz/172821#172821)

A simple example with your code.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    complexnode/.pic={
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and 1.5)
      (0,2.5) circle (1)
      (2.5,0) circle (1.5);}]

\draw (0,0) pic {complexnode} (3,3) pic[blue, rotate=30] {complexnode};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `pic` feature was SO missing from previous versions...it makes so much sense...TikZ is awesome!

Comment: This is definitely what I needed! Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to use a LaTeX `box` --- never had problems with this (although you probably can't connect to "internal" objects). For simple cases it's quite easy:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\genericfilt}
\savebox{\genericfilt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,
            >=stealth,
        ]
        \draw[thick, blue] (0,0) --(0.2,0) ..controls (0.5,1)..(1,1)..controls(1.2,1) and (1.8,0)..  
            node[black,left]{$H(f)$} (2,0) -- (2.5,0);
        \draw (0,0) node[below]{$0$} (1,0) node[below]{$f$} (2,0) node[below]{$\rightarrow\infty$};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) node[draw](filt){\usebox{\genericfilt}};
    \draw [<-] (filt.west) -- ++(-0.5,0);
    \draw [->] (filt.east) -- ++(0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example above]

Comment: does this work for more detailed plots containing many unique points?

Comment: @stars83clouds I think that you can put anything in the box. But I am not a TeXwizard... so I can be wrong. Try it and ask if something doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

The quick answer: you can just nest a `tikzpicture` environment into the contents of your node:

```
\node[draw] (A) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and 1.5)
            (0,2.5) circle (1)
            (2.5,0) circle (1.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}};
```

However this is discouraged for various reasons but it will work for simple designs.

Another option is using the new `pic` feature of PGF 3.0.

To answer to the last question: you can simply put an `\includegraphics` command into your nodes.